# How to send scheduled SMS messages in Android?

Tags: android, sms, android-sqlite, scheduled-tasks

I have to create an app which has some Mobile numbers in its database. It has to send SMS to everyone one of the number in the database at 12:00 AM everyday. I know how to add the numbers in database. But I don't know how to send scheduled messages for all those numbers. Any helps please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use alarmmanager to schedual a call to a method which fetch no. from your database and send your desired message to that number.

From android docs: 
**[AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)**:*This class provides access to the system alarm services. These allow you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the future. When an alarm goes off, the Intent that had been registered for it is broadcast by the system, automatically starting the target application if it is not already running.*

Answer (score 0):

Use SmsManager to send sms

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
```

And use alarm manager to do it every day

Look at this tutorial for more detail:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sending_sms.htm
http://javatechig.com/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android